# Parsing issue with Dart - [no build value ^ serializable ^ ]

Tags: json, serialization, dart, flutter, deserialization

Aye Aye good people,

[edited:

running this in dartpad

```
import 'dart:convert';
void main() {
  const String _json = '{"myListInt": [1]}';
  final Map<String, dynamic> _map = jsonDecode(_json);
  final List<int> _list = _map['myListInt'] as List<int>;
  _list.forEach((i) {
    String _s = i.toString();
    print(_s);
  });
}
```

returns

```
Uncaught exception:
CastError: Instance of 'JSArray': type 'JSArray' is not a subtype of type 
'List<int>'
```

in case I use

```
  final List<int> _list = List<int>.from(_map['myListInt'] as List<int>);
```

or

```
List<int>.generate(_map['myListInt'].length, (i)=>_map['myListInt'][i] as int);
```

returns

```
Uncaught exception:
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

]
what am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Francesco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this line

```
myListInt: List<int>.from(_map['myListInt'] as List<int>),
```

you can use

```
myListInt: List<int>.generate(_map['myListInt'].length, (i)=>_map['myListInt'][i] as int
```

Basically instead of casting the whole list, you have to cast each element one by one.

Comment: still same problem "Exception has occurred.
NoSuchMethodError (null)", but thanks for trying

Comment: honestly I didn't insist on your solution since with " as Iterable" my previous one worked, but thanks for following up, anyway your way to make a list from another in a single line is quite elegant, I'm definitely gonna use it in the future

Answer (score 0):

ok, using ""as Iterable"" works,

```
import 'dart:convert';
void main() {
  const String _json = '{"myListInt": [1]}';
  final Map<String, dynamic> _map = jsonDecode(_json);
  final List<int> _list=  List<int>.from(_map['myListInt'] as Iterable);
  _list.forEach((i) {
    String _s = i.toString();
    print(_s);
  });
}
```